# What's the difference between parable and allegory?

Tags: matthew, galatians

Matthew 13:10 English Standard Version

> Then the disciples came and said to him, “Why do you speak to them in **parables** [παραβολή ]?”

Galatians 4:24 English Standard Version

> Now this may be interpreted **allegorically** [ἀλληγορέω]: these women are two covenants. One is from Mount Sinai, bearing children for slavery; she is Hagar.

What is the relationship between παραβολή and ἀλληγορέω?

Comment: Parables are usually short illustrative stories, and allegories are metaphorical comparisons.

Comment: Events occurred to Hagar in real life. And she is a _figure_ of a covenant, allegorically. But there is no _parable_ told by anyone in scripture regarding Hagar.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Biblical Allegories & Parables, the timeline of the Messiah’s life has been disputed based on #Allegory (abstract interpretation) of ‘Seventy Sevens’ in Daniel 9:25-27 and the law of Leviticus 19:18 has been best explained through the #Parable (hypothetical explanation) of ‘the Good Samaritan’ in Luke 10:25-37.

#Allegory = Abstract Interpretation.
In his Eclogue Propheticae (III 46), Eusebius attempted to use abstract interpretation of the ‘Seventy Sevens’ prophecy in Daniel 9:25-37 to support the timeline of John 6:4 in regards to a proposed 3-year ministry instead of the 1-year chronology of the Synoptic Gospels (Mark,Matthew,Luke). Eusebius interprets Daniel 9:27 to be an #Abstraction of Yeshua’s ministry into a 1-week (7-day) value : [Daniel 9:27] “He will confirm a covenant with many for one ‘seven.’In the middle of the ‘seven’ he will put an end to sacrifice and offering.” - This example of #Allegory is a poetic device used to create a variable assigned to any amount of time when applied through abstract interpretation of dates.

#Parable = Explanation through Hypothetical Situation.
In the 1-year ministry of Yeshua (Jesus) of Nazareth as documented in the Gospel of Luke, Yeshua helps explain the Levitical law of ‘love your Neighbor as yourself’ from Leviticus 19:18. Yeshua tells His #Parable of ‘the Good Samaritan’ in Luke 10:25-37 which does not give an opportunity for interpretation but #explains clearly who a Neighbor is using the #hypothetical situation of a Samaritan willing to help a dying man instead of Priests. - The Parable is explaining the law, not interpreting it allegorically.